# Haskell interpreter, dont know how to run and test it

Tags: haskell, testing, functional-programming, monads, interpreter

I am working on an interpreter as a project task, in order to understand what I have to do, I decided to download the interpreter from the Internet and run it. I started the specified folder in WinGhci, but I don't know how to test it and what to do, can you help.

Here's the link of folder location.
https://github.com/kseo/poly

Its implementation of code in book "Write you a Haskell" chapter 7

.I don't know how to test it and what to do, can you help.

Comment: I understand that you want to implement an interpreter in the host language Haskell.  But, what is your *target* language (i.e., the language the interpreter is interpreting), or -- if it is a language of your own invention -- what sort of language is it?  Is it Haskell-like, or C-like, or Python-like or something else?

Comment: The reason I ask is that this example `poly` interpreter isn't a good example if the language you want to interpret isn't Haskell-like or ML-like.  The point of `poly` is to demonstrate Hindley-Milner type inference, not present a simple example of writing an interpreter.  You might learn something about general interpreters by looking at its code, but you'd learn a lot more by working through [Write You a Scheme](https://wespiser.com/writings/wyas/00_overview.html).  (And "working through" will be a lot more useful than just compiling someone's Git repository of the final code.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinGhci is unmaintained. The recommended way to install Haskell is https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/ nowadays. See https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/steps/ for how you can start using the Haskell tooling. And yes, you'll have to become familiar with the command line to be able to use Haskell effectively.

As for how to run poly, in the readme it says to run this command:

```
cabal run
```

Unfortunately, this is a very old repository. You'd need to go back to at least GHC 7.10.3, which you can still try to install but I don't know how easy it will be to use now (e.g. there are issues with 7.10 on linux at least).

Comment: Alternatively, use a newer GHC and try `cabal run --allow-newer=base`, which may or may not work. If it does work, it's preferable to lugging around an outdated compiler.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it doesn't work in this case